# Regular expression to remove endline space patterns

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a website updater that converts each **p** element to a textarea, the user types in the content then each textarea is converted back to **p** & I grab the resulting HTML & store that in my SQL database.

**My Problem:** In Internet Explorer, when I go to grab the HTML back it has slightly changed the html. For example:

```
// From this originally
<img id="headingpic"/><div id="myContent">  

// To this
<img id="headingpic"/>
<div id="myContent">
```

This matters because now on display there is a vertical gap between the img & the div below.

Sometimes IE inserts an "\n ", sometimes its an " \n" sometimes its just an "\n". I am trying to come up with a regular expression to remove these endlines(& spacing) no matter their pattern. I have ALOT of difficulty coming up regular expressions, they seem so cryptic to me.

If I explain my algorithm can you suggest the "character" that acheives this in regular expressions?

- For every ">" character: IGNORING ANY WHITEPACE OR ENDLINE CHARACTERS if the next character is an "<" then proceed
- For every char behind "<" if it is not == ">" delete it(or replace it with "")

I am trying to do this in either javascript or python:

```
# Python: should I use replace for this? Would my regular expression look something like this?
HTML_CONTENT.replace( "^[ \t\n\r]" ) # this removes all whitespace as far as I know
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this a different way:

firstly spilt by line.

```
html_content_list = HTML_CONTENT.split("\n"); // Split by line;
```

then remove all whitespace on the end with a `.trim()` (assuming we are talking about strings and one line each, test for null first)

```
for(var i in html_content_list)
{
    html_content_list[i] = html_content_list[i].trim();
}
```

then if it really does need a new line add it at the end:

```
html_content_list.join("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex needs a few more characters, or the \s:

```
HTML_CONTENT.replace( "^[ \t\n\r\f\v]" )
```

Or

```
HTML_CONTENT.replace( "^[\s]" )
```

> \v Matches a vertical tab \u000B.
>
> \f Matches a form feed \u000C.

---

I misunderstood the question at first, but here is how you would do it it python:

```
import re
HTML_CONTENT = """\
<img id="headingpic"/> abcdef
qwerty..??,ksjhe173((:$
<div id="myContent">
"""

print re.sub(">[^<]*<", "><", HTML_CONTENT)
```

Outputs:

```
<img id="headingpic"/><div id="myContent">
```

Or, if you just want to remove white space and newlines:

```
import re
HTML_CONTENT = """\
<img id="headingpic"/>

<div id="myContent">
"""

print re.sub(">[\s]*<", "><", HTML_CONTENT)
```

Outputs:

```
<img id="headingpic"/><div id="myContent">
```

Comment: Thanks: does this identify a ">" char then remove whitespace & format chars? Or does it just remove all format chars no matter where they are?

Comment: Updated answer.  I think I misunderstood the question at first.  Do you want no characters at all between the "><" or just remove the whitespace and newlines between "><"?